# Make js fire more than once?

Tags: javascript

I have a set of radio buttons, and I want this code to fire every time I click the radio buttons, but it only displays the div with its content once, and then it's no longer working. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the `#adr` div's `innerHTML` to nothing (' ') rather than its display to "nothing".
Change it to:

```
else if (document.getElementById('nothing').checked) {
    document.getElementById('adr').style.innerHTML = ''; // <-- here
}
```

Instead of:

```
else if (document.getElementById('nothing').checked) {
    document.getElementById('adr').style.display = 'none'; // <-- here
}
```

So instead of hiding the div (so when you next change its `innerHTML` nothing displays) you change the `innerHTML` to nothing, so that when you change it back it displays the content

Comment: Great! Any chance you could mark it as the correct solution? (The green tick by the upvote and downvote buttons) @JohnSmith

Comment: Sure, in 5 minutes! @joe_young

Answer (score 0):

This is because you set the display of the div to none in the block that is run if the nothing radio button is checked, and you don't set the display to block when it is set to the option that shows the div, so the display remains as none. My solution is this: Keep the contents of the street div the same, and only toggle its display value. Even better, toggle visibility instead, unless you MUST set display to none.